# Pandas Aggregate Function Dictionary Deprecation change

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i am trying to resolve the below warning for the piece of code . I understand the this feature has been deprecated on the new version of Pandas, could anyone please help in replacing the this code to work with new version of pandas with same effect.

4291: FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future version return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)

```
agg_func= {'Dividend Reference':{'Number of Postings':'count'},
          'Gross Dist USD':{'Total':'sum'},
          'WHT USD':{'Total':'sum'},
          'Net Dist USD':{'Total':'sum'}}

cus_due = main_due.loc[mask].groupby(['Income Region','Dividend Reference']).agg(agg_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change dict of dicts to dict of tuples, so is used named aggragation and then unpack them by `**`:

```
main_due = pd.DataFrame({
        'Dividend Reference':list('dddeff'),
         'Number of Postings':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'Gross Dist USD':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'WHT USD':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'Net Dist USD':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'Income Region':list('aaabbb')
})


agg_func= {'Number of Dividends':('Dividend Reference','nunique'),
           'Number of postingse':('Dividend Reference','count'),
           'TotalGross':('Gross Dist USD','sum'),
           'TotalWHT':('WHT USD','sum'),
           'TotalNet':('Net Dist USD','sum')}


mask = main_due['WHT USD'].gt(1)
cus_due = main_due.loc[mask].groupby(['Income Region','Dividend Reference']).agg(**agg_func)
print (cus_due)
                                  Number of Dividends  Number of postingse  \
Income Region Dividend Reference                                             
a             d                                     1                    2   
b             e                                     1                    1   

                                  TotalGross  TotalWHT  TotalNet  
Income Region Dividend Reference                                  
a             d                           17         8         9  
b             e                            4         7         9
```

Comment: ```
cus_due = main_due.loc[mask].groupby(['Income Region','Dividend Reference']).agg(**agg_func)
```
I get the below error message. 

TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

Comment: @prdp13 - tested in pandas `1.1.1` and working well for me, what is your pandas version?

Comment: right now i tried it on 0.22.0 . I will try it on the new version .

Comment: @prdp13 - it is really old, december 2017 version, [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.22.0.html), is possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: Yes , i will update and give it a try . Keep you posted.

Comment: `agg_func= {'Dividend Reference':{'Number of Dividends':'nunique','Number of postings':'count'},'Gross Dist USD':{'Total':'sum'},'WHT USD':{'Total':'sum'},'Net Dist USD':{'Total':'sum'}}
`
i use tuple in side an tuple in this case ?

Comment: @jezreal the above comment?

Comment: @prdp13 What are columns names before processing? `print(main_due.columns)`?

Comment: Apologies for the late response, below are the column names . 
`col_names =['Dividend Reference','Asset Code','Depot','Sub','Registration','Fund Code','Gross Distribution','WHT Distribution','Net Distribution','Receipt Amount','Contractual indicator','Responsibility Group','Income Status','Income Distribution Status','Responsibility Code','Responsibility Description','Market',
'Income Region','Currency Distribution','Super Group','Sub Group']`

Comment: @prdp13 - So output need triple `Total` column? What is reason for it? Not instead `agg_func= {'Dividend Reference':{'Number of Dividends':'nunique','Number of postings':'count'},'Gross Dist USD':{'Total':'sum'},'WHT USD':{'Total':'sum'},'Net Dist USD':{'Total':'sum'}}` is possible use 3 diiferent columns names like `agg_func= {'Dividend Reference':{'Number of Dividends':'nunique','Number of postings':'count'},'Gross Dist USD':{'TotalGross':'sum'},'WHT USD':{'TotalWHT':'sum'},'Net Dist USD':{'TotalNet':'sum'}}` ?

Comment: i am generating a report for distribution among few ppl , hence wanted to maintain the headers. If there is no other way , i am ok use new headers .

Comment: @prdp13 - by default is best avoid same columns names in pandas, so my solution create new unique columns names, answer was edited.